# Keep autocomplete suggestion panel open for multiple selection and close when clicked outside of panel in angular material 2

Tags: angular

I want to modify the autocomplete component for multiple selection.
What I want is that the suggestion panel should be opened for multiple selection via checkbox, and close it if user clicks outside of suggestion panel. As per the docs we can handle it via panelClosingActions but I cant find any way how to use it.

M able to keep Panel open via MdAutocompleteTrigger event and openPanel method but what happens is if 2nd index is selected and m selecting 4th index then 2nd index checkbox unticks and ticks again.

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" id=autoComplete>
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" 
[value]="state.name" (click)="handleAutocomplete()">
<md-checkbox [checked]="state.selected" [(ngModel)]="state.selected">
    <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
    <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
</md-checkbox>
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

@ViewChild('autocomplete', {read: MdAutoCompleteTrigger})
autoComplete: MdAutocompleteTrigger

handleAutocomplete(){
this.autoComplete.openPanel();
}
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491195/open-matautocomplete-with-open-openpanel-method/57117207#57117207

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging a lot I found out that material does not expose its methods to do so. So, in short, it's not possible yet

Comment: Ey, hitting the same problem now, have you figured out any update on this? very weird they haven't think in this common scenario right?

Answer (score 16):

I'm facing the same issue.

Only solution I found is to immediately reopen the options panel when an option is selected using mat-autocomplete optionSelected method.

HTML

```
<mat-autocomplete 
#auto="matAutocomplete" 
[displayWith]="displayFn" 
(optionSelected)="openPanel()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredSources" [value]="tag.id">
        <span>{{ tag.text }}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
openPanel(): void {
    const self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.autoTrigger.openPanel();
    }, 1);
}
```

This is not an elegant solution as the panel still closes and there is a blinking effect, but I couldn't find a better solution as MatAutocompleteTrigger panelClosingActions is readonly.

Comment: Ya I too found this solution but this isn't well technical solution, and after digging a lot I found out that material does not expose its methods to do so. So, in short, its not possible yet.

Comment: Is there still no better solution?

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing but the panel wouldn't open - thanks for your snippet with the timeout, I guess optionSelected must trigger before the panel closes.

Comment: You can avoid the blinking by using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: This option, together with @BenjaminKindle suggestion is working pretty well.

Answer (score 6):

Preventing event propagation for the autocomplete options

In the template:

```
<mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="checkOption($event)">
            {{ option.name }}
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And in the component:

```
checkOption(event) {
    // this prevents the click event to get to the autocomplete component
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: This only works when you click on the checkbox, but not when you select an option using the keyboard (arrow down + enter)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is relatively simple. You have to stop the propagation of the click, but when the click reaches the `md-option` it is already too late. Then an invisible prelayer is added with a `span` tag:

```html
<md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" 
 style="position: relative;"
 [value]="state.name">
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;"
   (click)="doWhateverWith(state); $event.stopPropagation()">
    <md-checkbox [checked]="state.selected" [(ngModel)]="state.selected">
      <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
      <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
    </md-checkbox>
  </span>
</md-option>
```

- Added a `span` with style `position: absolute` with `top,left,bottom,right` set to `0`.
- Added `position: relative` style to `md-option` so that the span expands correctly.
- The `(click)` event is added to handle the item in the `span`, since it will be the last one to receive the click event.
- The `$event.stopPropagation()` is added in this same `span`

This should be more than enough. I do it in a more recent version of Angular Material and it works perfectly. I assume that with this older version it will also work because it is still basic html/js.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me - invisible span tag that intercepts the click and prevents it from propagating to the `mat-option`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue with multiple autocomplete. Here is how I fixed it.

HTML: (the one I want to let the panel opened when I select an option)

```html
<mat-autocomplete  #emitterAuto="matAutocomplete" 
                   [displayWith]="autoCompleteDisplayLegalEntity"
                   (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected(0)">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let emitter of aFilteredEmitters$ | async"
                   [value]="emitter"> 
              <mat-icon *ngIf="emitter.is_organization">business</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon *ngIf="!emitter.is_organization">person</mat-icon>
              {{ displayLegalEntity(emitter) }}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="create-legal-entity" class="add-organization">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Ajouter…
      </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```js
import { QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChildren(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoTrigger: QueryList<MatAutocompleteTrigger>;
public onOptionSelected(value: number) {
    const self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.autoTrigger['_results'][value].openPanel();
    }, 1);
}
```

Value is the N `mat-autocomplete` where you want to apply this function.

Ex: If you want to open the panel of the second `mat-autocomplete`, `value` = `1`.

Hope it can help someone, and sorry for my English I'm French.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way I was able to achieve this, It's very informal & I won't say I'm proud of it but here's this

```
<mat-option style="position: relative;"
   *ngFor="let option of list;">
    <div style="position: absolute;top:0; left: 0; height: 100%; padding-inline: 15px;"
           (click)="$event.stopPropagation();optionClicked(option)">
        <span>{{option.name}}</span>
    </div>
</mat-option>
```

I have added position relative to mat-option & with css I was able give the child div the same height as mat-option (for width, I was not able to inherit it from mat-option so, I adjusted it with padding-inline). so my child div now covers mat-option and with '$event.stopPropogation()' I'm not letting my event reach mat-option

PS: This also means mat-autocomplete output events won't work since we blocking the event within the child div